# Facebook Instant Articles Audio Player

Tags: facebook, audio, facebook-instant-articles

How do you add an audio player to a Facebook Instant Article?

I'm not able to get my instant articles approved by Facebook because the web content from which I'm creating my articles has an audio player, but my instant article does not.

I've tried the html5 audio player with no luck, and the link Facebook reviewers provided me for guidance is a 404 : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/audio

Has anyone else had success?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs if https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/audio is not working for you

Comment: That is - if the instructions found on the page
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/audio
is not working.  If the page is 404, then see @morten-skogly 's answer below

Answer (score 1):

The audio Functionality and The audio caption seen in The original promo Content seem to have been removed, but I haven't been able to find any reason. I am considering using figure and uploading audio to YouTube or similar as a workaround.